# Movable Type on GoDaddy

Tags: godaddy, movabletype

I have deluxe linux shared hosting with godaddy, and it supports perl. but i dont know how to setup and use perl scripts.
Also i have no folder named CGI or CGI-BIN or anything like that.
As movable type requires me to put my content in the CGI folder, i cant. creating it also doesn't work.

So can you guide me on how to install movable type on godaddy. Also i dont want to spend money and install it from the godaddy hosting connection.
And please remember as i'm on a shared hosting, i might not be able to edit my apache server configuration file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, GoDaddy makes installing MT annoying, in several ways. There are some [notes in the wiki](http://wiki.movabletype.org/MT_Hosting_Quirks#GoDaddy)(and a pointer to the installation instructions) on some things to expect.